# iOS Safari when contenteditable=true and spellcheck=false clicking on a word that would have been marked as incorrect opens suggestion menu

Tags: html, ios, webview, safari, wkwebview

I have a `<div contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">` HTML element. Words that have incorrect spelling don't show with a red underline which is good but when the user taps on the word the correction menu opens and recommends different spellings.

No red underline on the word Iroh, good:

[image]

After tapping on the word a correction menu opens, bad:

[image]

If I set `autocorrect="false"` to my element then this menu does not appear when the word is tapped but then the user doesn't get spelling suggestions as the user types which I *do* want.

This is for an app using `WKWebView` so open to solutions in native Objective-C or Swift code. I’ve dug around in the WebKit source code for about an hour but am struggling to find the code which opens this menu. If I could find the WebKit source code controlling this menu maybe I could find a solution?

Comment: I’ve since found `UITextInputTraits.autocorrectionType`. With swizzling I’m able to modify `UITextInputTraits`. Setting it to `.no` turns off the word suggestions when a word is tapped but it also turns off keyboard predictive text which I want to keep.